# End-of-life date for ROS distributions?

Tags: ros, rosdistro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In a recent mailing list [announcement](http://code.ros.org/lurker/attach/3@20130304.213919.7a9a7dbf.attach) it was brought up that the ROS Electric buildfarm was going to be retired to make room for the ROS Hydro distribution. This led me to wonder: is there an end-of-life date for ROS distributions? I looked at the [target platforms](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#electric-emys-aug-2011) REP and the [Distributions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Distributions) wiki but I do not see it mentioned. Is a ROS distribution life cycle tied to all of the Ubuntu versions that are supported, the LTS Ubuntu release, or some other metric?

--

Edit:

To be more clear, is the term retire the same as end-of-life? What I mean is, even though ROS Electric will be retired from the build farm, will changes to core ROS packages still be pushed into ROS Electric and just not tested? Is there a date for when changes to core ROS packages are not updated with fixes or improvements? Is there a date for when ROS Electric packages will no longer be available from the repositories?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57349/end-of-life-date-for-ros-distributions?/) by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4347 on 2013-03-06

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-03-06**:
+1 I would like a clear answer on this one. My impression was that the ROS EOL was bound to the associated Ubuntu distributions EOL. Is this true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From what I understand from that email, it is implied that the lifetime of any rosdistro is three rosdistros (2 active + 1 development). So Fuerte will retire when I-ROS is in devel, and Groovy goes when J-ROS is in devel etc.

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2013-03-06**:
I should have been more clear -- edited original. Is retire the same as end-of-life?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-04-18**:
When it's retired that means that there will be no new binary releases. We will keep hosting the existing software as long as possible.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What weiin says.

Retired means that no changes will be actively made to electric, unless they actually break something critical and it is easy enough to make the change. Else it is up to the community to provide pull requests, and then possibly someone will merge. That is also end-of-life.

Packages for Ubuntu will still be provided as long as possible, there is no planned date to remove them.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2013-03-08**:
I'm curious, is this documented anywhere?

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-03-11**:
I don't know.